# React Native CLI: Android and ios setting issue

Tags: react-native, sdk, simulator

when I run `npx @react-native-community/cli doctor` I get this warnings.

```
Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 32.0.0
   - Version supported: .b31.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ● ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✖ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
```

**1)** Android SDK:
How to set up `.b31.0.0`?

**2)** iOS: How to fix `.xcode.env` error?

And when I run `npm run android` build succeeds.
But npm ~doctor shows these errors.